Is there a way to set IP address as primary key with EF Core (Npgsql)
Entity:
public class IPAddressInformation
{
    public IPAddress Address { get; set; }
    // ...
}

Configuration:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IPAddressInformation> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Address);

    // ...
}

Error:

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Property
'IPAddressInformation.Address' cannot be used as a key because it has type
'IPAddress' which does not implement 'IComparable< T>', 'IComparable'
or 'IStructuralComparable'. Use 'HasConversion' in 'OnModelCreating'
to wrap 'IPAddress' with a type that can be compared.' was thrown
while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns
supported at design time, see
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Note:
By default, Npgsql will map IP address to the inet type of Postgres which I prefer to have, not string.

You could convert it to a string and use that, or implement a custom converter, though I think an IP address as a PK sounds like a bad idea in the first place.

The error says quite clearly what you have to do: create a custom type that wraps IPAddress, and implement IComparable for it. And finally applicate HasConversion. Doesn't that work?

But I want the inet type in the database not string

Databases do not have any idea what an IP address is, they have varchar, int, float etc.

@DavidG of course postgresql understands what ip address is: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-net-types.html

@freakish Ah OK, though I still think using it as a PK is a terrible idea.

It is a terrible idea because the IP address of any device changes quite frequently. It's not just NAT, WiFi or mobile connections that change IPs. A site may use reverse proxies or services like Cloudflare. In any case, .NET's IPAddress isn't meant to be treated as a key, and so doesn't even implement IEquatable<>, never mind the sorting necessary for creating indexes. The native equivalent is the NpgSqlInet class, which ... doesn't implement IComparable

Why make Address a key instead of a normal field with an index ?

@PanagiotisKanavos | No specific reason, DB should not have duplicate rows for one IP, so I though why not make the IP itself primary key and reduce one extra column, but it seems that I have to make it a unique index and add a Guid key.

You should use an autoincrementing integer as the PK and index Address using a suitable index type (eg inet_ops) and add a UNIQUE constraint on it. GUIDs are horrible keys. They're essentially random so a new row can end up at the start or middle of a 1M row table instead of the end

This worked (based on @freakish idea for wrapping IPAddress class):
public class ComparableIPAddress : IPAddress, IComparable<IPAddress>
{
    public ComparableIPAddress(byte[] address)
        : base(address) { }

    public ComparableIPAddress(long address)
        : base(address) { }

    public ComparableIPAddress(ReadOnlySpan<byte> address)
        : base(address) { }

    public ComparableIPAddress(byte[] address, long scopeid)
        : base(address, scopeid) { }

    public ComparableIPAddress(ReadOnlySpan<byte> address, long scopeid)
        : base(address, scopeid) { }

    // Let's say IPv4 is always less than IPv6
    public int CompareTo(IPAddress? other)
        => AddressFamily == other?.AddressFamily
            ? ToString().CompareTo(other?.ToString())
            : AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork ? -1 : 1;
}

Change the property to
public ComparableIPAddress Address { get; set; }

Update the configs:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IPAddressInformation> builder)
{
    builder.HasKey(x => x.Address);

    builder
        .Property(x => x.Address)
        .HasConversion(
            v => new IPAddress(v.GetAddressBytes()),
            v => new ComparableIPAddress(v.GetAddressBytes()));
}

And this the migration:
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: ...,
    columns: table => new
    {
        address = table.Column<IPAddress>(type: "inet", nullable: false),
        // ...
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("pk_ip_data", x => x.address);
    });


Note: although this created the table, but I was unable to query data using EF Core, because it asked me to implement the IConvertible on the type.
